# Batch Command for folder refresh

Tags: batch

In my windows 10, I can't see latest files until I refresh the folder. Is there any batch command who can refresh only a particular folder.

The batch command, I am finding on Google is either restarting ‘Windows Explorer’ or refreshing the entire drive (tree D:/).

Thanks, Mohit

Answer (score 0):

Normally windows would correctly update a folder if new items are inside the folder.

This will not work when the files are not locally, but on a network share instead as windows cannot monitor the disk itself. Windows can get updates on the disk directly, just not over a network share. Windows will still update the content of that drive (aka refresh) but less often, as it just manually has to refresh the content.

If waiting is not an option, then you could remove the network mapping and mapping it again. Given that removing the network mapping would automatically close the explorer window anyway, just going out of the directory and back into (not using the back button, but physically clicking the folder) would be enough to refresh it. Also Pressing F5 would do the same.

Therefor, it is actually the quickest way to just refresh the folder manually. Hitting F5 seems to be the quickest way to me.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no batch command for it? Actually I need to incorporate that in Alteryx. So unfortunately manual refresh id not an option for me.

Comment: No, there is no scripted way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)** + **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** script:

```bat
@echo off 

> "%temp%\run_vbs.vbs" <nul (
      set /p "'=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory : "
      set /p "'=WScript.Sleep 3000: WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "{F5}""
    )  & cd /d "%temp%\." && %__AppDir__%cscript.exe //nologo "%temp%\run_vbs.vbs"

2>nul del/q /f "%temp%\run_vbs.vbs"
```

---

**1.** Use redirection to create your **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)** in run time:

```bat
> "%temp%\run_vbs.vbs" (
```

**2.** Use `set/p` to create one line **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs)** script:

```bat
      set /p "'=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory : "
      set /p "'=WScript.Sleep 3000: WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "{F5}""
```

- VBS file:

```bat
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory : WScript.Sleep 3000: WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "{F5}"
```

- VBS file does:

```bat
' :: Defines as the current explorer Window with the current folder
' :: Active the current folder (makes it foreground)

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirector

' :: Apply a sleep/pause time of 3 seconds
' :: Send the F5 key, simulate pressing/inserting the refresh

WScript.Sleep 3000
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "{F5}"
```

**3.** Go to the target folder and run your vbs script from there

```bat
cd /d "%temp%\." & %__AppDir__%cscript.exe //nologo "%temp%\run_vbs.vbs"
```

- Some further reading:

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Cd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [What does `/p` mean in `Set /p`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773805/what-does-p-mean-in-set-p/27773874)
- **[`WshShell.Sleep` / VBS](https://ss64.com/vb/sleep.html)**
- **[`WshShell.SendKeys` / VBS](https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)**
- **[`WshShell.Appactivate` / VBS](https://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html)**

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).ForEach{$_.Refresh()}
```

will refresh all open **Explorer** windows.